# Az powershell module availability on Microsoft hosted Agents

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have verified the installed software/packages from the [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2019-Server2019-Readme.md). No were mentioned Az module is available. Is Az module made available on the microsoft hosted agents? If not from when it will be available. We are using ADO custom build tasks and Azure automation accounts with Azure RM module. What should be the best migration to Az module.

Comment: Ask Microsoft when the `Az` module will be built in to the hosted agent. No one except them can say.

Comment: Just want to check whether below answer is helpful for you. Consider [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it is help for you, and also it would help other community members who easier search that useful information:-)

Answer (score 1):

Az module is available if you use the latest Azure Powershell task (`AzurePowerShell@4`). It would pull the Az module automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @4c74356b41's answer. We have expanded and preloaded some modules in **Azure Powershell@4** task, including `Az` module. This task would load `Az` cmdlets automatically which do not need you to use `Install-Module` cmd anymore.

If you do not want to use this task, but only **Powershell** task, the `Az` module can also be used, just use one cmd to install module firstly:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Force
```

This command can be applied in all agents, no matter it is hosted or private one.

With cmd `Get-InstalledModule` checked, you can see that it is installed successfully:

[image]

---

If you want to know the best migration to `Az` module, check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-2.8.0). It express the details of how should you configure the environment for the migration to succeed. And how should the migration be applied suitable when the environment meets the migration criteria.

> The latest available release of AzureRM is 6.13.1. If you don't have
>   this version installed, your existing scripts may need additional
>   modification to work with the Az module beyond what's described here
>   and in the [breaking changes list](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/powershell/azure/migrate-az-1.0.0?view=azps-2.8.0).
>
> If your scripts don't work with AzureRM 6.13.1, update them according
>   to the [AzureRM 5.x to 6.x migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/migration-guide.6.0.0?view=azurermps-6.13.0). If you use an earlier
>   version of the AzureRM module, there are migration guides available
>   for each major version.

Answer (score 1):

AZ is already downloaded on the agent, just not installed

Something like this could work

```
$env:PSModulePath += ';C:\Modules\az_7.1.0'
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PSModulePath;]$($Env:PSModulePath)"`
```